# Передача значения input в переменную

Tags: php, html, javascript, css

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку содержимое поля input передавалось в переменную $text?

```
    <?php
      $text = 'file';
    file_put_contents("$text.php", "Тест в файл", FILE_APPEND);
    ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="file_name" size="20">
    <input type="submit" value="Создать">
    </form>
```

Данный скрипт создает файл на сервере. Нужно, чтобы при создании файла можно было указывать имя создаваемого файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде, чем задавать подобные, так сказать, вопросы "в духе Hello World", пошуршите для начала парочку страниц гугла на тему POST запросы в PHP. Но я не только советовать могу, я и ответ могу даже дать! Смотрите:

```
 // этот скрипт, как вы, надеюсь понимаете, обрабатывает запрос в "index.html"
   <?php
    $post = $_POST["file_name"]; // вот мы получаем значение текстового поля =)
    // что-то там далее делаем...
    $text = 'file';
    file_put_contents("$text.php", "Тест в файл", FILE_APPEND);
    ?>
    ...
    <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="file_name" size="20">
    <input type="submit" value="Создать">
    </form>
```